# How To Start Application Automatically on Reboot?

Tags: android

How do I activate or run app automatically on phone boot. I have rooted phone with my app in it,so that it wont be removed on factory reset. What I want is to activate it automatically after factory reset without user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

You may find this useful http://www.androidsnippets.com/autostart-an-application-at-bootup

Good Luck

Comment: I want To Run it After Factory Reset , where App is in inactive State.

Comment: Can't I write Script on Rooted phone that could activate the app on boot?